# find records using Rails 3 where and 'not equal'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, find

I have the following find which does not work

```
self.participants.where(:role => "Celebrant", :created_at => year..Time.now, :board_id => !current_board.id)
```

What I want to to find the participants that satisfy the above and

```
:board_id not equal to current_board.id
```

How can I do this with rails 3 where?

Comment: You can also use the Metawhere gem, at http://erniemiller.org/projects/metawhere/

Comment: I usually use sql like "AND id NOT IN (?)", passing a collection of ids for "?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd want something like this:

```
self.participants.
     where(:role => "Celebrant", :created_at => year..Time.now).
     where('board_id <> ?', current_board.id)
```

You have to drop down to string conditions and SQL snippets for "not equals" as [Hash conditions are a bit limited](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions):

> Only equality, range and subset checking are possible with Hash conditions.

Comment: Wow I did not know you could chain where statements. This works great.

Comment: @chell: The query methods can be chained and mixed and matched and chained as needed; they're lazy and won't do the real work of talking to the database until you force them by asking for some data.